# Use AJAX in a WordPress Plugin to Get Data From Custom Database?

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, wpdb

I've created a PHP script that works great stand alone.

I need to convert this script to a WordPress plugin. I've created a custom table in the WordPress database.

When i try to get data back I get the `wp-admin` main page. All the data needs shown on the `wp-admin` page.

```
function applyfilter() {
    var timeperiod  = $( '#timefilter' ).val();
    var datefrom    = $( '#pdate1' ).val();
    var dateto      = $( '#pdate2' ).val();
    var status      = $( '#status' ).val();

    $('#lists').html("Loading....");
    $.ajax( {
        url     : 'index.php',
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : 'action=ajax&timeperiod=' + timeperiod + '&datefrom=' + datefrom + '&dateto=' + dateto + '&status=' + status,
        success : function( response ) {
            $( '#lists' ).html( response );
        }
    } );
}
```

`index.php` is the main file in my plugin folder.

Comment: Have you checked [these](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax)?

Comment: Start here: [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this for send ajax...

```
function my_action_javascript()
{
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var data = {
                'action': 'my_action',
                'whatever': '1'
            };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                if ($('#menu_order').val() == '' || $('#menu_order').val() == '0')
                    $('#menu_order').val(response);
            });
        });
    </script> <?php
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript'); 

function my_action_callback()
{
    $whatever = intval($_POST['whatever']);
    //$whatever += 1;
    echo $whatever;
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this tutorial which detail steps for how to use ajax. may help you
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tutorial-ajax-wordpress/

Comment: Link only answers are not quite recommended here. You can add some explanation along with link.